# Fixed nav falling out on smaller viewpoint

Tags: html, css, fixed, nav

I have a set width layout with a fixed nav. When I make the browser size smaller than the set width, I would like to be able to scroll across and view the entire width of the nav. Check this jsfiddle:

### [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dLcxmy8y/)

```
.container {background:red;width:400px;height:800px;position:relative;}
nav {background:blue;position:fixed;top:0;padding:20px 0;width:400px;}
nav a {color:white;margin:0 5px;border:1px solid lime;}
```

Check the fiddle and then make the window really narrow, you can't scroll to the right side of the nav because it is fixed to the left. In short, I would like it to be fixed to only the top.

Answer (score 0):

You just set the width of the navigation bar to `400px`. Set it to `100%`.

```
.nav{
    ...
    width: 400px; // Change this to 100%

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dLcxmy8y/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't fix my solution however, in my real project I have a wide background image for the nav, having content collapse down into the viewport width doesn't cut it.